# PHP array keys as nth value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Associative array as

```
$array = Array([0]=>a[1]=>b[2]=c[3]=>d);
```

I need to build an array from this array where the the first key becomes a and the value becomes b & 2nd key becomes c and value becomes d.
Output should be:

```
$finalarray = Array([a]=>b,[c]=>d);
```

I have tried this following code:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
$arr[$value] = array_slice($array, 1, 1);
$finalarray[] = $arr;
}
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: Okay, so what problem do you have doing this?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Post the code which you have tried

Comment: I would start by looking at how you created the first array, and do the right thing there rather than trying to fix it later

Comment: Posted the code I have tried.Please check it

Comment: Seems like a candidate for a for loop starting at zero and stepping by 2

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to loop on your first array, but to skip one value on two:

```
$array = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
$finalArray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i+=2) {
    $finalArray[$array[$i]] = $array[$i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://3v4l.org/91ukT) may help:

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d'); $b = array();
$length = count(a)%2 ? count($a)-1 : count($a);
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
    $b[$a[$i]] = $a[++$i];
}
var_dump($a,$b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Little changed your code:

```
$i=0;
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
 $value_2=$value++;
 if($i%2==0)
$arr[$value_2] =$value;
$i++;
//$finalarray[] = $arr;
}
echo"<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: `$value` is not a pointer. and you don't want to mess with pointers in any language, specially PHP.

Comment: It will give the OP required output

Answer (score 0):

If your array is associative , below code may help you

```
<?php
   $array = array(0=>'a',1=>'b',2=>'c',3=>'d');
   $new_array = array();
   for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i+=2)
   {
     $new_array[$array[$i]] = $array[$i+1];
   }
   print_r($new_array);
?>
```